# Trying to write subversion post-commit script to export PHP tu a public folder

Tags: svn, export, hook, post-commit

I am trying to deploy a PHP application using subversion and post-commit script. I've been looking for how to write post-commit script but i can't get it to work.

Configuration : I have a svn folder installed on my server (OVH) in `homeX.XX/svn/test/`

My post-commit script should EXPORT to  `homeX.XX/dev/`

I don't know how to write the proper path when using

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir dev
chmod 777 dev
svn export svn+ssh://XXXXX@www.xxxx.com/homeX.XX/XXX/svn/test dev
```

in my POST-COMMIT script. I've been looking for answers but did not find any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SVN documentation ([here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)):

> The Subversion repository executes hook programs with an empty environment—that is, no environment variables are set at all, not even $PATH.

I've been stung by this problem a few times. Basically the easiest way to write SVN commit hooks, although not very clean, is to hardcode all files and directories that you need as absolute paths.

So in this case, your script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# SVN-related variables
svnuser=XXXXX
svnhost=www.xxxx.com
svnpath=/homeX.XX/XXX/svn/test

# Local paths
exportpath=/homeX.XX/dev

# Make export dir if it does not exist
if [ ! -e "$exportpath" ]
then
    mkdir $exportpath
fi

# These permissions are very lenient! Are you sure you want this?
chmod 777 $exportpath

# Do the SVN export
export svn+ssh://$svnuser@$svnhost$svnpath $exportpath
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank, I came upon this script already but could not make it work. I'm aware of the absolute Path  issue, but in the script you posted, I don't understand how it manages to LOGIN to ssh... Does a psot-commit script already has rights and only need to supply the user name in the svn+ssh:... stuff string ?

Comment: Up, can't make it work... would you we kind enough to tell me how can I get the error output ? I'll have more luck id I know where it bugs...